# UICollectionView Error in converting ios 6 to ios 7

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, uicollectionview, ios7

Here I have developed the app in IOS6, when I open the App in IOS 7 with Xcode 5 In Collectionview errors are throwing

```
file://localhost/Users/asaraa/Documents/IOS/Projects/Asaraa/Embassy/UI-Changed/Washington/IOS7/20130918/Mphasis/RootviewController.xib: 
    error: Class Unavailable: UICollectionView on iOS versions prior to 6.0
```

How can i resolve this error, Could any body help me please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me from this description of your error:

```
UICollectionView on iOS versions prior to 6.0
```

That you're trying to build an app that has the deployment target (the oldest OS version) set to something older than iOS 6. [UICollectionView only works on devices running iOS 6 & newer OS'es](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html). Do you have your project settings set to run this app with iOS 5 or 4?

And if you change it to iOS 6, do you get better results?

Comment: Thanks, As Per your instruction when i changed to IOS6 its working but I need to work the app in all ios 5,6 and 7 versions. How can I do this Is there any solutions, kindly help me

Answer (score 0):

`UICollectionView` didn't exist before iOS 6.  You could try the open source [PSTCollectionView](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView) , which supports iOS 5 and aims to be a drop-in replacement.